# How to create a bar chart with non-numeric X axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is my DataFrame `df`:

```
    bin             qty
0   (0.0, 25.0]     3634.805042
1   (25.0, 50.0]    1389.567460
2   (50.0, 75.0]    1177.400000
3   (75.0, 100.0]   898.750000
4   (100.0, 125.0]  763.000000
```

I want to create a bar chart like a histogram. Y axis should be `qty` and X axis should be `bin`, for example "(0.0, 25.0]", rotated vertically.

I tried this, but it fails because `bin` is not numeric:

```
plt.bar(df.bin, df.qty, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try, using Pandas Plot:

```
df.plot.bar('bin','qty', alpha=.5)
```

Output:

[image]

Using matplotlib:

```
x = pd.np.arange(len(df['bin']))
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))
ax.bar(x,df['qty'])
width = .35
ax.set_xticks(x + width // 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['bin'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How can I configure it, for example, apply something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))`, coloring, etc? Therefore i prefer matplotlib.

Comment: @Dinosaurius See this [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to use matplotlib, your bin column isn't a valid object. [matplotlib.pyplot.bar](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) requires a sequence of scalars equivalent to the left value of each bin. So your dataframe should look like

```
        bin             qty
    0   0.0     3634.805042
    1   25.0    1389.567460
    2   50.0    1177.400000
    3   75.0     898.750000
    4   100.0    763.000000
```